# Why imgur adds white background to some png images, and to others not with Alamofire and Swift?

Tags: ios, alamofire, imgur

This is how I simply upload images to Imgur using Alamofire and Swift:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload")!
private var headers: [String: String] {
    ["X-Token": "[mytokenhere]", "Authorization": "Client-ID [myidhere]"]
}

Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipart in
    if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image.image) {
         multipart.append(data, withName: "image", fileName: "image.png", mimeType: "image/png")
    }
}, to: url, headers: headers, encodingCompletion: { result in
    //convert result image from result here
})
```

Example before upload, original image (as you can see, it adds white background even here on SO, why?):

[image]

And after upload, returned url to an uploaded image:

[image]

Originally on computer and iPhone it look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how Imgur behaves when your image size exceeds a limit - it converts your image into a JPEG. See the [Imgur Help page](https://help.imgur.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000083326-What-files-can-I-upload-Is-there-a-size-limit-) on upload limits.

> The maximum file size for non-animated images (think JPG, PNG, etc) is 20MB. PNG files over 5MB will be converted to JPEGs.

Note that for anonymous uploads, this limit is 1MB:

> Non-animated images over 1MB for anonymous uploads and 5MB for account holders will be lossily compressed.

You can see that it has been turned into a JPEG by inspecting the response JSON. The "type" key would indicate the type of image actually uploaded. For example, this is returned when I anonymously uploaded a png larger than 1MB:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        ...
        "type": "image/jpeg", // <---
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a good point. What does it mean "anonymously uploaded"? I have changed uploaded png file size to less than 1mb and it worked perfectly. How can I increase the limit for non anonymous upload?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk You cannot increase the limit. This is their rules. To make a non-anonymous upload, you need some user’s access token. See https://apidocs.imgur.com/#authorization-and-oauth Use the access token you get from the user as the bearer token.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk in case it’s not clear, the `Authorization` header in your upload request should say `Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN` instead of using a client id.  For how you get the access token, see the link.